# Update mysql json query with python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have a json field suppose from *table T1 and field F1* `{"X":[{"a":"1","t":"2"},{"a":"2","t":"4"}]}`
If i want to **update** my **t=2 to t=10 for a:1**, how to do this? 
What will be the normal mysql syntax?

i tried something like this it just update t=10 value separately

```
UPDATE T1 set F1 = JSON_SET(F1, '{"a":"1","$.t", "10"}') where id = 1;
```

tried with this..it just add another value to the same field like

`{"X":[{"a":"1","t":"2"},{"a":"2","t":"4"}],"t":"10"}`

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That's not valid JSON syntax.

Comment: See the [Documentation on functions that modify JSON values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html)

Comment: update T1 set F1 = JSON_SET(F1, '{"a":"1","$.t", "10"}') where id = 1; tried with this..it just add another value to the same field like `{X:[{"a":"1","t":"2"},{"a":"2","t":"4"}],"t":"10"}`..i tried @Barmar

Comment: Put your coe in the question, not a comment.

Comment: It's still not valid JSON syntax. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path` parameter is wrong. You need to index into the `X` array to get to the property you want to change.

```
UPDATE T1
SET F1 = JSON_SET(F1, '$.X[0].t', '10')
WHERE id = 1
```

To search for `a = 1` and update the corresponding `t`, you can use `JSON_SEARCH`. It returns a string with quotes around it, so you have to remove those. Then you have to replace `.a` with `.t` to get the property you want to set.

```
UPDATE T1
SET F1 = JSON_SET(F1, REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(F1, 'one', '1', null, '$**.a'), '"', ''), '.a', '.t'), '10')
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar, ur solution is working..u r super ..thanks a lot

Comment: here t value updated with respect to index 0,1..suppose i need to update for that particular "a":"1" dict no in "a":"2", i have to go with key or value name,when a==1 ..how to do that?

Comment: Added the query that does it using `JSON_SEARCH`